# custom Membership provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am new in ASP I am doing a web Site with a custom Membership provider, because  I don't need a BBDD to save my user only XMLFile.

I am folling this example

http://madskristensen.net/post/XML-membership-provider-for-ASPNET-20.aspx

but now I don't Know, how to create my logon method to comunicate with my custom MembershipProvider.

There are any examples o documentations to learn  about this.!!!!

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application it will contain an AccountController an related Account views that should work with your custom membership provider.

The only change you should need to make is to change the "type" to your custom provider in the membership section of the web.config (see sample below):

```
 <membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="MY.CUSTOM.MembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```